# How do I configure Dockerized Lambda Image Configuration with CDK?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cdk

Currently using DockerImageFunction, but I can’t figure out how to set the CMD Override. Any advice would be appreciated.

Repo: https://github.com/alphaHades/Dockerized-Lambda-NR/blob/main/lib/docker-lambda-aws-stack.ts

[image]

Comment: Check the docs for `DockerImageCode`.

Comment: I tried, but couldn’t figure it out until now. Was expecting an example ‍

Answer (score -2, accepted):

```html
// docker image function const dockerFunc = new lambda.DockerImageFunction(this, "DockerFunc", { 
code: lambda.DockerImageCode.fromImageAsset( "./image", { 
      cmd: ['newrelic_lambda_wrapper.handler'] // assign cmd override for image config } ),

});
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example which is taken directly from the CDK documentation. It contains all relevant features, but importantly shows how to set `cmd`:

```
// The code below shows an example of how to instantiate this type.
// The values are placeholders you should change.
import * as cdk from 'aws-cdk-lib';
import { aws_ecr_assets as ecr_assets } from 'aws-cdk-lib';
import { aws_lambda as lambda } from 'aws-cdk-lib';

declare const networkMode: ecr_assets.NetworkMode;
declare const platform: ecr_assets.Platform;
const assetImageCodeProps: lambda.AssetImageCodeProps = {
  assetName: 'assetName',
  buildArgs: {
    buildArgsKey: 'buildArgs',
  },
  buildSecrets: {
    buildSecretsKey: 'buildSecrets',
  },
  buildSsh: 'buildSsh',
  cacheFrom: [{
    type: 'type',

    // the properties below are optional
    params: {
      paramsKey: 'params',
    },
  }],
  cacheTo: {
    type: 'type',

    // the properties below are optional
    params: {
      paramsKey: 'params',
    },
  },
  cmd: ['cmd'],
  entrypoint: ['entrypoint'],
  exclude: ['exclude'],
  extraHash: 'extraHash',
  file: 'file',
  followSymlinks: cdk.SymlinkFollowMode.NEVER,
  ignoreMode: cdk.IgnoreMode.GLOB,
  invalidation: {
    buildArgs: false,
    buildSecrets: false,
    buildSsh: false,
    extraHash: false,
    file: false,
    networkMode: false,
    outputs: false,
    platform: false,
    repositoryName: false,
    target: false,
  },
  networkMode: networkMode,
  outputs: ['outputs'],
  platform: platform,
  target: 'target',
  workingDirectory: 'workingDirectory',
};
```

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_lambda.AssetImageCodeProps.html

Comment: I saw this doc yesterday, but couldn’t understand how to leverage AssetImageCode interface, but was able to finally figure out how use it within dockerImageFunction class through code construct